# Android StackOverflowError in ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection

Tags: android, stack-overflow, viewgroup

I just went to android market to publish an update to my app and noticed there a few new errors reported from existing installs.  While I can understand (and attempt to do something about) most of them, this one leaves me rather puzzled:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
... this line repeats about 200 times or so ...
```

This is all there is - no other information of any kind.

I'm totally stumped as to where to start investigating this.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked down the problem.  It seems to me like a bug in Android, which is exhibited when a View's `visibility` is explicitly set to `VISIBLE` but the view itself and the view's parent is not added to the main view.

I finally got around the problem by adding the ListView in question to XML instead of creating it in the code and moving the code `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to after the entire view is added to the main view (i.e. parent hierarchy can be traced from each child all the way to the beginning).

At least I'm not getting this error any more.

Answer (score 10):

That appears to be a method added in ICS, so it's 4.0 and over. Looking at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection%28%29) it seems like you have some kind of view loop in your hierarchy since it's *apparently* the `child.resetResolvedTextDirection();` line doing it. In other words, one of your `ViewGroup` classes in your layout has somehow gotten added as a child to itself somewhere down the line.

Comment: I see.  I'm quite certain that a view can't be added to itself (directly or indirectly) as a child - otherwise all sorts of problems would ensue.  I'll try to get ics simulator and try running through the debugger there - maybe will be able to find the issue.

Comment: Yup, there's a `parent` check that you would _think_ would avoid that. But I can't explain a recursive loop in any other way. Unless it isn't recursive and your view hierarchy is really that deep.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you inflate the view such that `inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_topic, this);`
and the parent of this view is still not visible / rendered on to the stage.

Make sure you render it after the parent is visible or call

```
View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_topic, null); // null will give warning but it wont throw an exception
        this.addView(child);
```