# Android StackOverflowError in ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection when adding ListView to LinearLayout

Tags: android, viewgroup, stack-overflow

I had asked one question about this error before ([Android StackOverflowError in ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180626/android-stackoverflowerror-in-viewgroup-resetresolvedtextdirection)), however now I managed to reproduce the error in the emulator and narrowed down the specific place where this problem occurs.

When I'm starting my activity, I have an `AsyncTask`, which pulls the necessary data from my server and creates all views.  Inside the `run()` method of the AsyncTask, I'm creating a custom view (and adding it to the main view of the activity - but that's not important now):

```
ListingView listing = new ListingView(MainActivity.this);
```

`ListingView` is my custom view class, which extends from `LinearLayout`. In the constructor of this custom view, I have this code:

```
public ListingView(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    ...

    LayoutInflater infl = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View top = infl.inflate(R.layout.listing, this, true);
    this.addView(top);
    ...

    LinearLayout lst = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.LayoutListingTop);
    tblVenues = new ListView(context);
    tblVenues.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    tblVenues.setItemsCanFocus(true);
    tblVenues.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(venueListener != null && venues.size() > 0) { venueListener.selected(venues.get(position)); }
        }
    });
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    lst.addView(tblVenues, lp);    //this line causes the problem

    ...
}
```

In this custom view class, `tblVenues` is declared as

```
private ListView tblVenues;
```

And the XML that's being loaded is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/LayoutListingTop"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@color/white">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
               android:layout_width="170dp"
               android:layout_height="62dp"
               android:src="@drawable/ookl_logo"
               android:layout_gravity="left"
               android:adjustViewBounds="false"
               android:scaleType="fitXY">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_marginBottom="5px"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:textColor="@color/black"
              android:text="@string/love_culture"
              android:id="@+id/TextView01"
              android:textSize="28dip">
    </TextView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:id="@+id/ButtonBar"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@drawable/buttonbar"
                  android:paddingLeft="10px"
                  android:paddingRight="10px"
                  android:paddingTop="5px"
                  android:paddingBottom="5px">

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnListVenues"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="45dip"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:text="@string/button_venues"
                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_venues_on"
                     android:textColor="@color/venue_blue"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                     android:textSize="9dip">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnListEvents"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="45dip"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:text="@string/button_events"
                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_events_off"
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                     android:textSize="9dip">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnListTrails"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="45dip"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:text="@string/button_trails"
                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_trails_off"
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                     android:textSize="9dip">
        </Button>

        <Button android:id="@+id/BtnListObjects"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="45dip"
                     android:background="@null"
                     android:text="@string/button_objects"
                     android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon_objects_off"
                     android:textColor="@color/white"
                     android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                     android:textSize="9dip">
        </Button>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/TxtLabelDistance"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:text="@string/label_distance"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="right|bottom"
                  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:layout_marginTop="-17px"
                  android:textSize="9dip">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

This all works perfectly fine on Android form 1.6 up to 3.x, however on Ice Cream Sandwich (4.0) line

```
lst.addView(tblVenues, lp);
```

results in `StackOverflowError`:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedTextDirection(ViewGroup.java:5131)
... this line repeats about 200 times or so ...
```

There's nothing else useful in the LogCat.  The whole ListingView is not even added to the main activity view yet, because the error is thrown essentially from its constructor.

I'm a total loss as to what may be the problem.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After banging my head against the wall for quite some time and trying all sorts of different approaches, I believe, this really is a bug in an android, which is exhibited when a View's `visibility` is explicitly set to `VISIBLE` but the view itself and the view's parent is not added to the main view.

I finally got around it by adding the ListView to XML and moving the code `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to after the entire view is added to the main view (i.e. parent hierarchy can be traced from each child all the way to the end).

At least I'm not getting this error any more.

Answer (score 5):

[Old question, but I wasn't pleased with the answer, so adding my notes in hope that they're helpful for someone else.]

Aleks -- I agree with the core issue being an Android bug, but tracing into the code (I encountered a similar issue recently) I believe the issue can be prevented by inflating with the attachToRoot parameter set to false. This is because with attacheToRoot==true, the returned view is the 'root' parameter you passed in. In your case that is 'this', which then add a child of the current view (you're adding the object as a child of itself). This seems to confuse android (it really should check for instance equality).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

"[Returns] The root View of the inflated hierarchy. **If root was supplied and attachToRoot is true, this is root; otherwise it is the root of the inflated XML file**."

Making this change resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: Interesting... Yes, this question is old - and I did resolve the issue at the time (apparently).  However just now I received another report of the same issue - specifically on Samsung Galaxy 4 device.  Strangely enough, it doesn't occur on other devices with the same version of android, therefore this must be a bug in Samsung's implementation.  Unfortunately, I don't have SG4 myself, so it would be quite difficult to debug.  I'll give your idea a try.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: This is actually a bad advice, that I learned using the API through the years. See top voted answer. You must add a parent view in, even if it's hard to obtain. I believe that's because the `layout_` parameters in your root element from the inflated XML depend on the parent layout. For example `layout_below` (or something like this) is available if your element is a child of a `RelativeLayout`. At least I got related problems when I passed `null` in.

I was debugging Android itself, because I made the same mistake, and I found the real reason. The real problem lies within these lines:

```
View top = infl.inflate(R.layout.listing, this, true);
this.addView(top);
```

As you can see, you pass `this` as the second parameter of inflate, that already adds the inflated view to `this`, so when you do `this.addView(top)`, it gets added one more time. You have two options to correct a mistake like this: delete the line `this.addView(top)`, or replace `this` with `null`. I haven't tried the second one, but it should work as well, and is probably a better solution, if you want to manipulate the views before adding to the parent after inflation.

The `attachToRoot` parameter, that BigDSK mentioned might suffice, but I find that passing `null`, and addViewing after that, or omitting the `addView` is a more bulletproof solution (IMHO), so I thought I would share.

Comment: Instead of replacing `this` with `null`, you can use `infl.inflate(R.layout.listing, this, false)` and keep the `this.addView(top)` line.

Comment: lucidbrot, Yeah, I never pass `null` any more. This is actually a bad advice. I had trouble from passing in null. Thanks for the comment, I forgot I wrote this, now I'll update.